# Change value in XML based on specify parameter id

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd

**Original file (Test.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Shift_JIS"?>
<root>
    <!--標準項目-->
    <parameters kind="standard">
        <parameter id="a" name="replace">120</parameter>
        <parameter id="b" name="replace">120</parameter>
        <parameter id="c" name="replace">120</parameter>
        <parameter id="d" name="replace">00000001</parameter>
        <parameter id="e" name="replace">1</parameter>
    </parameters>
</root>
```

**CMD Script**

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "old="
    set "new=3" 

    for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in (
        'find "e" "C:\Test.xml"'
    ) do set "old=%%a"

    powershell -Command "(gc C:\Test.xml) -replace '%old%', '%new%' | Out-File -encoding ASCII C:\Test.xml"

exit 0
```

**Modified file (After executed the CMD script)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Shift_JIS"?>
<root>
    <!--標準項目-->
    <parameters kind="standard">
        <parameter id="a" name="replace">320</parameter>
        <parameter id="b" name="replace">320</parameter>
        <parameter id="c" name="replace">320</parameter>
        <parameter id="d" name="replace">00000003</parameter>
        <parameter id="e" name="replace">3</parameter>
    </parameters>
</root>
```

1. As a result after executed the CMD script, it does not check for the specify id and changed all the value 1 to 3 in each line.
2. Can anyone advise which code wrong in the CMD script and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the output of the `find "e" "C:\Test.xml"` command? What is the output of the `CHCP` command? Also, please comment out or remove `@echo off` in order to see what is happening.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: The desired output just to change the id="e" value to 3. other remain the same value as in original. i have tried to removed the @echo off but the result still the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your source data stays formatted like this, the following command will work. I admit that this is brittle if the source text changes, but I do not fully know your requirements.

```
Get-Content test.xml | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '(.*id="e".*>).*(</p.*)', '${1}3$2' }
```

Using `-encoding ASCII` is not likely to work well if you have Shift-JIS characters in the source data file.